# How to create a list from a C# Dictionary return object

Tags: javascript

My Ajax call returns a Dictionary from C#.

```
 return = pp.Shares
        .Select(c => new
        {
            c.Url,
            c.Name
        }).ToDictionary(d => d.Url, d => d.Name);
```

The above returns a JSON object

This means my return in JavaScript looks like:

```
key1: value
key2: value
key3: value2
```

I need to pass all *values* as an array to another function.

Do I have to loop through all the return values and create a new array for the values to pass to the required function, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder, but I *know* the key. The point is, I don't care about the key as I only need to extract the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes that the input is fixed and cannot be formatted e.g. as JSON.

---

First split your input up into lines, i.e. by `\n` or `\r\n` depending on the input. Then split the lines again into key and value and pick the values:

```js
var input = 'key1: value\nkey2: value\nkey3: value2';

var lines = input.split('\n');
var values = lines.map(function(line) {
  return line.split(': ')[1];
});

console.log(values); // ["value", "value", "value2"]
```

---

**Edit:** Since your input is already provided in JSON format, it is even easier. `JSON.parse()` the string and extract the object values:

```js
var input = '{"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value2"}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(input);

var values = Object.keys(parsed).map(function(key) {
  return parsed[key];
});

console.log(values); // ["value", "value", "value2"]
```

Comment: There is, as far as I can see, no \n. I updated my post and will try this, but I'm surprised there is a newline ?

Comment: Well, the input in your question has line breaks. Note that I have no knowledge about C# dictionaries and their implementation.

Comment: I can only say sorry. It returns a json object. I will try and add a screen shot of the DEV tools

Comment: See my edit. Working with JSON makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: Why am I parsing it if it's already an object?

Comment: If it's already an object, you can skip the parse step. If you receive a JSON string, you need to parse it to a JavaScript object first. Note that there is no such thing as a _JSON object_. Either it's still a string, or it is a JavaScript object.

Comment: Is a "javascript object formatted as json" better terminology (this makes no difference to my question, I'm just curious)

Comment: You could call it a JavaScript object _serialized_ as JSON! :-) And yes, in this case, you will need to parse the JSON first.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. I already upvoted so can't give any more :(